# Spring Mongo's find operation freezes on windows server 2008 Machine

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am currently using Spring's Mongo persistence layer for querying MongoDB. The collection I query contains about 4G of data. When I run the find code on my IDE it retrieves the data. However, when I run the same code on my server, it freezes for about 15 to 20 minutes and eventually throws the error below. My concern is that it runs without a hitch on my IDE running on my 4G Ram windows PC and fails on my 14G ram server. I have looked through the Mongo Log, and there's nothing there that points to the problem. I also assumed that the problem might be an environmental issue since it works on my local spring IDE, however the libraries on both my local pc are the same as the ones on my server. Has anyone had this kind of issue or can any one point me to what I'm doing wrong. Also weirdly, the find operation works when I revert to Mongo's java driver find methods.

I'm using mongo-java-driver - 2.12.1
spring-data-mongodb - 1.7.0.RELEASE

See below sample find operation code and error message.

`List<HTObject> empObjects =mongoOperations.find(new Query(Criteria.where("date").gte(dateS).lte(dateE)),HTObject.class);`

The exception I get is:

```
09:42:01.436 [main] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[Hansard]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Cursor 185020098546 not found on server 172.30.128.155:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$CursorNotFound: Cursor 185020098546 not found on server 172.30.128.155:27017
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2002)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1885)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1696)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTempate.java:1679)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:598)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:589)
at com.sa.dbObject.TestDb.main(TestDb.java:74)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$CursorNotFound: Cursor 185020098546 not found on server 172.30.128.155:27017
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.throwOnQueryFailure(QueryResultIterator.java:218)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.init(QueryResultIterator.java:198)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.initFromQueryResponse(QueryResultIterator.java:176)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.getMore(QueryResultIterator.java:141)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.hasNext(QueryResultIterator.java:127)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:551)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1871)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

## In short

The MongoDB result cursor is not available anymore on the server.

## Explanation

This can happen when using Sharding and a connection to a `mongos` fails over or if you run into timeouts (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#closure-of-inactive-cursors).

You're performing a query that loads all objects into one list (`mongoOperations.find`). Depending on the result size, this may take a long time. Using an `Iterator` can help to leverage but even loading huge amounts using `Iterator`s is limited at a certain point.

You should partition the results if you have to query very large data amounts using either paging (paging gets slower the more records you skip) or by querying with splits of your range (you have already a date range, so this could work).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Thing is the result size is actually quite small. Also, the same query works perfectly on my IDE. Even when finding a single object the server still hangs and subsequently throws the same exception. How can I control cursors using spring mongo.

Comment: AFAIK, altering a cursor using Spring Data Mongo is not possible. Have you tried to get a thread dump (jstack) to see, where the process hangs or running your server in debug mode and attaching the debugger while the process runs? The cursor timeout smells, that something happens within the mapping, which consumes a lot of time.